# What can we do so that people regard proper grammar in their questions?

Tags: discussion, grammar

I don't understand why this is so commonplace on StackOverflow. I mean sure it's a bit more understandable for new users, but honestly if you don't even put in the effort to make a question readable, how can you expect other people to put in the effort to give you a quality answer?

It is especially bad for people who may not have the best English. That fact alone is perfectly okay, but at least make an effort to capitalize your "i"s and use "you" instead of "u".

Maybe I'm just weird, but from the first question I ever posted on this site, I've always used proper spelling, capitalization, and grammar. I do use abbreviations and "texting" language on social networks such as Facebook, but I've always considered SO to be a community in which professionalism is more highly valued. I'm looking for any insight you guys can offer on this matter.

What can we do to enforce using of proper English in posts, and not a slang that may be very hard to understand for non-native speakers?

Comment: As this question stands, the `primarily opinion-based` close reason applies. I think that this is not a particularly good fit for Meta. While I agree, and gladly concur, it's... not really an answerable question, unfortunately.

Comment: I see, and upon reflection I agree with you. Perhaps this was not a good question to ask on Meta.

Comment: It's an interesting question, and I'd like to definitively know why myself. It just can't be answered. Thanks, though, for making all our lives better by using proper grammar :]

Comment: You're missing commas around "sure" in your second sentence. :Þ

Comment: Haha, I'm certainly not trying to say that everyone should be a grammar nazi. I just think it's good to spend just a couple of extra seconds bothering to properly capitalize, punctuate, and write out the longer versions of "u" and "plz".

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. Just joking around...

Comment: Have you considered that some of them learnt their English from the Internet and may simply not know any better? I mean, that's not an excuse, but sometimes it might be an explanation. And as I already wrote, in that situation they need someone to give them a hand, not a kick.

Comment: That certainly is a possibility, but I find it hard to conceive that this represents a significant portion of the people we are talking about. And while I agree that we should "give them a hand," perhaps identifying them is the hardest part.

Comment: "hard to conceive that this represents a significant portion of the people we are talking about" - It doesn't tell much about the actual users, but half of SO's traffic is from countries where English isn't the primary language http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/where-in-the-world-do-stack-overflow-users-come-from/ . I'm pretty sure those users are accountable for most of the posts with poor grammar.  As a non-native speaker myself, I can't understand why people don't just use some spell checker though.

Comment: @kapep I can. Some of them use SE at work, and have stupid managers and stupid helpdesk teams that refuse to let them install stuff they are not supposed to need. Can't say how many of them are in that situation, but I know for a fact *some* are.

Comment: @goddfree you also have to consider that the first generation of texters is starting to enter the work force, so the language of texting (which has also become internet shorthand) is also coming with them.  That could contribute to the usage of all lower case and the over use of abbreviations.

Comment: Proper grammar is one thing. Non-native speakers may have problems with it. Slang is something else. This is usually done by lazy native speakers.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I understand that, as I am part of that generation. I'm more interested in the psychology of this situation. Obviously the younger generation that grew up in English-speaking countries are capable of proper spelling and grammar, but yet these people specifically choose not to use it. As I said, I've always considered StackOverflow to be a more professional community. Everyone here has a specific goal they're looking to achieve. Do these people not consider SO as a more professional network, or do they choose to continue to ignore grammatical issues despite considering it so?

Comment: @goddfree you are correct, there are plenty that are capable of writing correctly and choose not to do it.  I'd love it if we could find a way to solve it as text-speak lingo drives me up the way.  I don't even use it when I'm texting.

Comment: (Probably bad) idea - built-in spell-checker and either prevent posting questions with excessive spelling mistakes, or send it to the low quality queue. [Decent browsers](https://www.google.com/chrome) have built-in spell-checkers, but my guess is (1) users don't use them (either the browser or the spell-checker), (2) users ignore the mistakes or (3) users have other languages set as the default. It will probably need to be a largely custom-built spell-checker, as code blocks needs to be ignored, as well as domain-specific words, or code-related 'words' in non-code.